# Library for tree output of data for analysis

Tags: haskell

For convenient analysis of data I'd like to use a library which for the following code:

```
data SomeType = A [String] Int | B | C Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

main = do 
  let theData = A ["a", "b", "c"] 9 : C 3 : B : []
  putStr $ treeString theData -- `treeString` is the implied library function
```

would produce an output similar to the following:

```
- A:
| - - a
| | - b
| | - c
| - 9
- C:
| - 3
- B
```

Is there such a library? Or maybe a better approach to such a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Data.Tree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html) has [`drawTree`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html#v%3adrawTree) and [`drawForest`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Tree.html#v%3adrawForest) functions with similar formatting, so you can write a function to convert your data structure to a `Tree String` and then use `drawTree`.

```
import Data.Tree

data SomeType = A [String] Int | B | C Int deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

toTree :: SomeType -> Tree String
toTree (A xs n) = Node "A" [Node "*" (map (flip Node []) xs), Node (show n) []]
toTree B        = Node "B" []
toTree (C n)    = Node "C" [Node (show n) []]

main = do 
  let theData = A ["a", "b", "c"] 9 : C 3 : B : []
  putStr $ drawTree (Node "*" (map toTree theData))
```

**Output:**

```
*
|
+- A
|  |
|  +- *
|  |  |
|  |  +- a
|  |  |
|  |  +- b
|  |  |
|  |  `- c
|  |
|  `- 9
|
+- C
|  |
|  `- 3
|
`- B
```

Comment: Thanks! The output is very good, but the `toTree` implementation looks like pure boilerplate. Isn't there a more generic solution?

Comment: @NikitaVolkov: You can probably do something with generics, but you're  going to want special cases for things like lists or strings so that they don't render as huge trees of `(:)` nodes.

Comment: Found out how to do this generically. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

Adding to hammar's answer. Here's how one can do a generic conversion to `Data.Tree`:

```
import Data.Tree
import Data.Generics
import Control.Applicative

dataTree = fix . genericTree
  where
    genericTree :: Data a => a -> Tree String
    genericTree = dflt `extQ` string
      where
        string x = Node x []
        dflt a = Node (showConstr (toConstr a)) (gmapQ genericTree a)
    fix (Node name forest)
      | name == "(:)" 
      , a : b : [] <- forest
        = Node "*" $ (fix a) : (subForest $ fix b)
      | otherwise = Node name $ fix <$> forest
```

But for this to work on one's data types, they must have an instance of `Data`, which can easily be achieved by adding a `{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}` pragma and making the type derive from `Typeable` and `Data` like so:

```
data SomeType = A [String] Int | B | C Int | D [[String]] 
  deriving (Typeable, Data)
```