# Casting to a typeclass

Tags: generics, haskell

I want to implement a generic function which will try to convert any type to a list. I've tried to achieve this with the help of `Typeable`:

```
import Data.Data
import Data.Foldable
import Control.Applicative

asFoldable :: (Typeable (a b), Foldable z, Typeable (z b)) => a b -> Maybe (z b)
asFoldable = cast

asList :: (Typeable1 a, Typeable b) => a b -> Maybe [b]
asList x = Data.Foldable.foldr (:) [] <$> asFoldable x
```

The code above compiles just fine without the `asList` definition, but with it, it keeps barking on the ambiguousness of the `t0` type variable, referring to the `a` I guess. Now I've tried to trick around with it but it only works when I specify the specific types for the cast like `Maybe [String]` or `Maybe (Set String)` and etc.

My guess is that I got to fool the compiler with the `asFoldable` type declaration, but it still wouldn't work because it doesn't support casting to typeclasses. Is this true? Is there a better way to try to convert any type to a list? Is there any at all?

Comment: What could it mean to convert arbitrary types to a list? What would an Int be as a list? A Bool? A function from Strings to Integers?

Comment: @AndrewC A `Nothing`, as the type signature suggests. Basically the algorithm I was trying to implement was to test if a value is `Foldable`, then fold it to a list and wrap it in a `Just`, and return a `Nothing` otherwise

Comment: @NikitaVolkov There's no way to test for instances dynamically like that.  (Well, you could build a table of presence/absence of an instance in a given module using Template Haskell, but that would be a bit over-the-top!)  The whole point of the type class system is to *statically* classify values, not dynamically identify them.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov By the way, `asFoldable` works without any "tricks", but it doesn't do what you wanted it to.  It dynamically checks whether `a ~ z`, but only after *statically* enforcing that `z` (and therefore `a`, if the result is a `Just`) is an instance of `Foldable`.  You have to pick a specific `z` to test against when using it, which is why you got the error about ambiguity.

Comment: @Ptharien'sFlame A quite reasonable explanation on why casting to typeclasses can't be achieved. Why didn't you post it as an answer? It would be nice if you also answered whether there are other ways to achieve what I am trying to.

Comment: @AndrewC I need a generic function to implement a conversion to a `Data.Tree` for the purposes explained in [these question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455023/library-for-tree-output-of-data-for-analysis). I can't imagine a way I could solve this without generics.

Comment: What's wrong with the already existing `toList :: Foldable t => t a -> [a]`?

Comment: @DanielWagner Nothing. I just missed that function. Anyway that wouldn't solve the problem anyway

Comment: @NikitaVolkov My question was explicitly, "why doesn't that solve the problem"?

Comment: @DanielWagner Because it requires the input to have a `Foldable` instance, but I need it to be generic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way (without Template Haskell, and that's almost always overkill) to test for presence of an instance of a type class dynamically.  The right way to convert arbitrary structures to other arbitrary structures in a generic manner is to use `Data.Data`, which is the generics that @hammar was talking about in your other question.

```
toTree :: Data a => a -> Tree String
toTree x = Node (show $ toConstr x) $ gmapQ toTree x
```

Of course, as @hammar also said, you may want to treat lists and strings differently.